# pandas matching pattern and appending to column multiple times in same dataframe

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe which is built from the following code:

```
d = [{'AX':['chr=1','pos=2'], 'AVF1':[], 'HI':['chr=343', 'pos=4'], 'version_1':[]},
      {'AX':[], 'AVF1':['chr=4', 'pos=454'], 'HI':[], 'version_2':[]},
      {'AX':['chr=3', 'pos=32'], 'AVF1':['chr=6', 'pos=12'], 'HI':[], 'version_3':[]}]

frame = pd.DataFrame(d)

frame

cols = ['AX','AVF1','HI']

f = frame.T

lst = []
f['temp'] = f.index
for i in f.iloc[-3:, -1]:
  lst.append(i)
f = f.drop(columns={'temp'})

f.columns = [lst, f.columns]
f

chrs = pd.DataFrame(index=f.index, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([f.columns.levels[0], ['chr']]))
pos = pd.DataFrame(index=f.index, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([f.columns.levels[0], ['pos']]))



f = pd.concat([f,chrs], axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
f = pd.concat([f,pos], axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)

f = f.drop(f.index[[-1,-2,-3]])
f
```

```
        version_1                        version_2                                version_3
        0                 chr      pos   1                   chr        pos       2                 chr      pos
AX       [chr=1, pos=2]   NaN      NaN    []                 NaN        NaN        [chr=3, pos=32]  NaN      NaN
AVF1     []               NaN      NaN    [chr=4, pos=454]   NaN        NaN        [chr=6, pos=12]  NaN      NaN
HI       [chr=343, pos=4] NaN      NaN    []                 NaN        NaN        []               NaN      NaN
```

I am trying to look at each column beginning with a int (0,1,2) and pattern match for the patterns beginning "chr" and "pos" up to the first comma i.e. "chr=1" or "pos=454". I am then trying to append the value to the corresponding column.

Desired output:

```
        version_1                        version_2                                version_3
        0                 chr      pos   1                   chr        pos       2                 chr      pos
AX       [chr=1, pos=2]   chr=1    pos=2      []             NaN        NaN        [chr=3, pos=32]  chr=3    pos=32
AVF1     []               NaN      NaN    [chr=4, pos=454]   chr=4      pos=454    [chr=6, pos=12]  chr=6    pos=12
HI       [chr=343, pos=4] chr=343  pos=4  []                 NaN        NaN        []               NaN      NaN
```

The real dataframe I'm doing this on has a much larger number of columns so listing each column may not be a viable option. I tried the code below but I'm not good at pattern matching.

```
f['0'].str.extract(pat='chr')
```

Comment: Why do you create this dataframe in the first place? Cant' you start with a simpler dataframe of just 3 columns (0,1,2) or (version_1, 2, 3) and generate the final dataframe after extraction of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you should start with a simpler structure. Do not create the output structure, then extract the data but rather **extract first the data, then create the new columns**

Starting from your complex structure, the first step would be to get the 0,1,2 columns. Then we `stack` (there is actually no need for a regex as you have lists):

```
cols = pd.to_numeric(f.columns.get_level_values(1), errors='coerce').notna()
# array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False])

# get a single column with the chr/pos lists
s = f.loc[:, cols].droplevel(1, axis=1).stack()

# create a 2D structure from the extracted data and replace in origincal DataFrame
f.loc[:, ~cols] = (pd.DataFrame(s.to_list(), columns=['chr', 'pos'], index=s.index)
                     .unstack(1).swaplevel(axis=1))
```

output:

```
cols = pd.to_numeric(f.columns.get_level_values(1), errors='coerce').notna()
# array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False])

s = f.loc[:, cols].droplevel(1, axis=1).stack()

f.loc[:, ~cols] = (pd.DataFrame(s.to_list(), columns=['chr', 'pos'], index=s.index)
                     .unstack(1).swaplevel(axis=1))
```